# Getting "Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted" error when sending array

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with getting a "Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted" when calling a SQL query thru php. I believe the array creator is stuck in a loop, somehow.

My php:

```
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
        die("DB query fail: " . mysql_error());
    }
}


$con = mysql_connect("mysql15.000webhost.com", "***_mw", "***");
if (!$con) {
        die("DB connect fail: " . mysql_error());
}

$mySqlDB = "a9414387_build";
$dbSelect = mysql_select_db($mySqlDB, $con);
if (!$dbSelect) {
    die("db select fail: " . mysql_error());
}


$sku = $_POST['serching'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory1 WHERE id LIKE '{$sku}%'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$des = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$matches = mysql_num_rows($result);
$json = array();
if ($matches > 0) {
    while($des) {
        $bus = array(
            'description' => $des['description'],
            'price' => $des['price'],
            'sku' => $des['id'],
            'type' => $des['type'],
        );
        $jsonString = array_push($json, $bus);
    }

    echo json_encode($jsonString);

    } else {
        echo json_encode(NULL);
    }

die();
?>
```

But, if i comment out:

```
while($des) {
            $bus = array(
                'description' => $des['description'],
                'price' => $des['price'],
                'sku' => $des['id'],
                'type' => $des['type'],
            );
            $jsonString = array_push($json, $bus);
        }
```

and replace $jasonString with $des i get something like:

```
{"0":"4040284","id":"4040284","1":"F","active":"F","2":"T","defaults":"T","3":"aurora,superNova","model":"aurora,superNova","4":null,"defmodel":null,"5":"mboard","type":"mboard","6":"105","price":"105","7":"Intel H67 (1155) Motherboard","description":"Intel H67 (1155) Motherboard","8":"1155","socket":"1155","9":"Not available at this time.","infoDiv":"Not available at this time.","10":"IntelH67Socket1155Motherboard.jpg","image":"IntelH67Socket1155Motherboard.jpg"}
```

I am not looking to extend the memory size, b/c one small array should not be this big.

Comment: The interesting part of your error message is missing. Anyway, now that you know what you want to do, what is preventing to do that?

Comment: Your code is liable to SQL injection.  Instead of using `$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory1 WHERE id LIKE '{$sku}%'";`, I strongly suggest that you use prepared statement: `$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory1 WHERE id LIKE ?";` and then bind the variable to `"{$sku}%"`.

Comment: Technically he shouldn't be using the mysql commands at all as they have been deprecated. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$des = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$matches = mysql_num_rows($result);
$json = array();
if ($matches > 0) {
    while($des) {
```

You need to re-assign `$des` inside your loop; otherwise, you're constantly checking the same database row. Try something like this:

```
$matches = mysql_num_rows($result);
$json = array();
if ($matches > 0) {
    while($des = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

$des was set to the next record of the array and you then while on it. This means it will always be true as the array has contents, which causes an infinite loop as you thought. The `$des = mysql_fetch_array($result)` will not get called again to move on to the next result.

Try removing the first `$des = mysql_fetch_array($result)` and replacing `while($des)` with:

```
while($des = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```